# Apache commons ftpclient not connecting

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am writing an application to download files from ftp server. The code exits with error - UnknownHostException. The site is valid and I have opened it in filezilla. The code follows -

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private FTPClient mFtp;
    private FTPFile[] files;
    public Downloader() {
        mFtp=new FTPClient();
        try {
            mFtp.connect(InetAddress.getByName("fenils.in"));
//          mFtp.connect("ftp://fenils.in");
            mFtp.login("*****", "******");
            mFtp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            files=mFtp.listFiles("/pankaj/beta");

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            for(FTPFile f:files){
                fos=new FileOutputStream("alpha/"+f.getName());
                mFtp.retrieveFile(f.getName(), fos);
            }
            fos.close();
            mFtp.logout();
            mFtp.disconnect();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. My mistake. I neglected to set the uses internet permission. I found the answer here [Java ftpclient application doesn't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579676/java-ftpclient-application-doesnt-connect)